# Kernel file not getting executed on jump from bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

Recently i was trying my hands on the 16 bit assembly and thought to write down a boot loader with a kernel file to make something similar to  an operating system. My Boot loader code is completely verified and its loading the kernel code onto the memory. But once it gets loaded i am not able to jump to that code and execute it. Here are some of the relevant details.

```
    call    load_dir                ; Load the directory table into the memory
    call    search_kernel           ; Search for Kernel Address (First Logical Cluster ) in the root directory
    call    load_fat                ; Load file allocation table into the memory
    call    read_fat
```

As seen in the code above first load_directory loads the complete directory (13 Sectors ) into memory . Once loaded search_kernel tries to find a file named "KERNEL.BIN" and if found loads the word from offset 26 to ax ( First Logical Cluster). After that the code loads the fat (8 Sectors to be precise) into the memory and starts reading it( read_fat) and loads the data into (buffer+10752). 
**Till here everything was fine.**
I verified the contents and it was the correct code located in that address.
Now the problem comes. After this i wrote the statement

```
    mov     bx,[buffer+10752]
    push    bx
    ret
```

This in fact should technically trick the ip register into loading my desired instruction and executing it. The code of KERNEL.BIN is

```
BITS 16
jmp  short main
main:
    mov     ah,0EH
    mov     al,'H'
    int     10H
    jmp $
```

Now this should print character H onto the screen( Testing Purpose) but it dosent work. What mistake have i made. Please Help!

Regarding my segment registers:

Except Stack Segment Register  all other segment registers are loaded the same value.

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code. Although not the problem in this case your kernel file should be setting the appropriate segment registers and/or setting an origin point with an ORG (without it, it defaults to 0).

Comment: As well `mov     bx,[buffer+10752]` takes the 2 bytes stored at memory address buffer+10752. Is that what you intended? (Hard to tell without the entire bootloader).

Comment: Basically that was a small mistake I actually had a Jmp to main routine

Comment: I will correct it

Comment: As I have made a short Jmp to main it generates a 2 byte instruction code .this is the reason sir why I pushed a word into stack

Comment: Are you sure you intended to use `mov     bx,[buffer+10752]` and not `lea     bx,[buffer+10752]` .I'd recommend you put your entire bootloader into github and make it available. Better yet, try debugging this in BOCHS.

Comment: Sir I did it but no effect. Also sir I would surely put this project on github and I will debug today itself with bochs.  Thank you sir. Its really fun to work with assembly

Comment: You will have to make all your code available to make this an [mcve]

Comment: Sir but the code is not completely commented.  It would technically be useless if I tried to put the code. That why I didn't make the entire code available

Comment: Once commenting the code I will surely make the complete code available

Comment: Put on github or some other place where I can take a look at it. I don't need it to be commented to figure out why this fails. Other than that I suggest you use a debugger like the one in BOCHS.

Comment: PS: j`mp  short main
main:` doesn't do anything useful beside go to the next instruction.

Comment: `push bx` / `ret` is a clunky way of writing `jmp bx`.  (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html).